# Permission denied even after role is granted

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am assigning a role permission to create database. Same role is assigned to a login user, but when I try to create a new database using the login user to which the role is assigned I get permission denied error.

> Could not execute statement. Permission denied, database master, owner
>   dbo. You need the following permission(s) to run this command: CREATE
>   DATABASE. Sybase error code=10331 Severity Level=14, State=3,
>   Transaction State=0 Line 1

I tried this with 15.5 and 16. Am I doing something wrong here? Do we have to take care of any other parameters? I went through this discussion

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3932505

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess: the role is not enabled for the session. When granting a user-defined role to a login, by default it is not enabled at login time. This can be modified with sp_modifylogin or (in 15.7) 'alter login'. To enable a role in a session, use 'set role ... on'.
Use sp_activeroles to determine which roles are currently enabled.

Comment: The role is activated. I checked using sp_activeroles.